# Symfony Profiler: show response content?

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, profiler, postman

Currently using the **Postman REST client** to debug my ajax calls, I would like to know if there a way to **show the response content** of an ajax response inside the **Symfony profiler** ?

I can only seem to find the Response Headers inside the Response tab...

[image]

I might mislead myself, is it even the role of a profiler to perform such a feature ?

Any response, explanation or link to a related topic would be much appreciated.

Thank you and have a good day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [is] there a way to show the response content of an ajax response inside the Symfony profiler ?

There's no built in way to see this kind of information. This would go a bit beyond profiler's domain, which is showing profiles of your PHP application.

However, on the toolbar itself you can see the ajax requests made while rendering the page. You can click on profiles of specific ajax requests, or copy their URLs.

This feature [was introduced in Symfony 2.6](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-ajax-requests-in-the-web-debug-toolbar).

[image]